# Powerapps suspense list items error waiting for bracketclose found error

Tags: list, items, powerapps

added a suspension list to a powerapps projects, trying to add items editing "Items" property with: ["12","24","36"] but receiving a error: expecting "bracketclose" found "error" and the first item, "12" is in a different color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your locale.  In an English locale your expression should work, but for example in a Latin locale then you should change , into ; so using this

```
["12";"24";"36"]
```

PS Also in Latin locales ; should be changed into ;;